# Sending the date from client side or server side while filtering the data between 2 dates?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have a tab with following options:

```
Tab1         Tab2         Tab3                    Tab 4                     Tab 5
January   February    Last 3 Months           Last 6 Months            Last 12 Months
```

Now based on above selected tab, I would like to call my Server side API and filter out the data.

**Approach 1:**

```
Public ActionResult FilterData(Datetime from, Datetime to)
{
    // Filter out data between 2 dates
}
```

**Approach 2:**

```
Public ActionResult FilterData(string selectedTab) // Tab1 or Tab2 or Tab3 etc...
{
    if(selectedTab =="Tab1")
    {
        // Construct datetime object for Jan month
       //filter jan data;
       
    }
    ....
}
```

The only problem I see with second approach is I might select inappropriate date because I will be getting date and time using Server side api and server might have different date as what the client might be having.

I will really appreciate if someone can guide me in the correct direction.

So which approach I should go with and why?

Comment: What do you mean by server might have a different date than the client?  Do you mean because of time zones? if that's the case, the local times need to be translated to UTC before performing the query.

Comment: @Fran Yes because of the time zones. So are you suggesting that I should go with second approach?

Comment: No, I'm just suggesting that 1. you are either going to need to pass  time zone  and make the translation some where.  The where is up to you.  You api may expect only times in UTC.  If that's the case, I'd make the translation in the client and only pass UTC dates.  But to me, approach 1 would make more sense.  What does an API know about tabs?  Those are a UI concern and should stay in the UI.

Comment: @Fran So on the client side, I should use javascript to fetch the Time zone and then construct the date and then pass it to Server side API?

Comment: Just use the internal javascript Date functions.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 1):

Approach 2 brings up a separation of concerns issue. You would driving the behavior your API based on an arbitrary UI construct (tabs and their ordinal position). Each tab actually represents a time period (1 month, 6 months, etc), so approach 1 is a more resilient  design. If every client that uses the API either converts local times to zulu times (OK but fragile) or includes a timezone identifier in the dates it submits (much better) when calling the API you can easily overcome the challenge of clients in multiple time zones.

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me. So when calling my API, I should use Javascript to pull the timezone info and pass it to my server side api or construct datetime object on the client side itself and just pass the dates to the server side API?

Comment: Make sure you format that dates used in your AJAX call according to what the API is expecting, which is an ISO 8601 format (remember JSON has no type for expressing dates, they are just strings). Use the JS date object's toISOString() method to convert the date into a string that the server can understand.